# How to access store certificates from client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a web application in which i need to sign a document at client end.client should select the certificate and be able to sign from that certificate.I am using this code to access the store certificates:-
 X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

But this is returning certificates from server.
How to access certificates at client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now you might have a small conceptual problem: the client has to send that to the server.

If you are using a web app, you should think on using a activeX control or a java applet...

The code is the same as you have there.

Keep in mind that you should not send the client's private key, and if you are signing or cryptographing something, that should be done in the client.